# Howto print out the pagination for EntityFieldQueries?

Tags: 7, entities, paging

I have this code that uses an `EntityFieldQuery` object:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'yacht')
  ->propertyCondition("status", 1)
  ->pager(3, 1);

// […] switch case defaulting to:
$query->fieldOrderBy("field_bautyp", 'value', "asc");
// […]

$query->execute();
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
return theme('yacht_display', array('nodes' => $nodes));
```

And in the yacht_display.tpl.php

```
<some HTML-Code and iteration over the $nodes>
<?php var_dump(theme_pager()); # => NULL ?>
```

It apparently works; when I add `?page=2,5` to the URL I get different results.
Now I need to render the pager. Simply calling `theme_pager()` does not work; calling `theme('pager', array("element" => 1))` always returns `NULL`.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: updated the code to its current state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `->initializePager()` part is wrong; why would you do that?
Kill that line, and call `execute()` as usual.
Just calling `theme('pager')` should be enough; I am not sure why it fails. (Maybe because of the call to `initializePager()`.)

Comment: That is true; `EntityFieldQuery::execute()` already invokes `EntityFieldQuery::initializePager()`. `execute()` should always be executed on query objects.

Comment: in fact i do call `EntityFieldQuery::execute()` later. I added some code to my example. And it's still not working, even when I remove `initializePager()` :(

Comment: The problem might be that another PagerQuery is run between yours and when you call theme('pager'), it only works if it is called directly after the query is executed. You can call it in your page callback and then pass it to the template.

Comment: dunno what was wrong with me or the code. But removed `initializePager()` **again** and simply called `theme('pager')`… it now works.

Answer (score 0):

Change here: ->pager(3, 1) to ->pager(3).
It will work.

Comment: please elaborate your answer